# How to export a searchable PDF from images by macOS Monterey (Live Text)

Tags: macos, livetext

In macOS 12 (Monterey), there is a new feature called [Live Text](https://www.apple.com/macos/monterey/features/). It can recognize text in the images by OCR.

MacOS's Preview app lets you select text in an image file, and also lets you convert the image to a PDF file. Meanwhile, I did not find a way to export the image into a searchable PDF which can let you search and select text in that exported PDF file.

Is there any way to convert images into a search PDF file in macOS Monterey with Live Text (OCR)?

Comment: FWIW, Live Text does in my experiments a much better OCR job than Tesseract and tools that build on it (like ocrmypdf). So being able to save the results of Live Text is huge. Hopefully Spotlight will at some point start using Live Text too without needing the explicit conversion first.

Answer (score 3):

In Preview 11.0 running under macOS Ventura 13.4.1 on an MacBook Air with M2 processor, this works.  First, make sure all the text in the document is selected, because for long documents, detecting all the text takes time.  If you clover-A too soon, you're only going to save that text that was identified so far.  Then, in the File > Export... dialog, check "Embed Text", and Save.

The text becomes searchable in other PDF readers.

Comment: What is „clover-A“?

Comment: ⌘-A (command-A) looks like -A

Comment: Also, for long documents, I've taken to doing a search, e.g., "clover-F test" and waiting until the spinning that indicates the search is still in progress completes.  It doesn't have to find anything, but the completion ensures all the text that can be identified is identified.  Then clover-A and Export.

Comment: As of Ventura 13.6, there's no need to search or select all. You only need to export with the "embed text" option on, and Preview will spend some time doing the OCR (less than 2 secs per page in my M1).

Answer (score 1):

In macOS Monterey Ver 12.3.1 and Safari Ver 15.4 at least you can load an image in Safari and click "File" -> "Export as PDF...". **Just make sure you enlarge the image to 100% or else Safari will make a ugly formatted PDF**. Also, any text highlighted before you export will show up in the PDF doc.

I have not found a way yet to export an Image file as a text readable PDF from Preview.

Answer (score 0):

On Sonoma / 14.3.1, I have discovered that if you right-click an image in Finder and go to `Quick Actions > Create PDF`, the resulting PDF is OCR'd.

I don't know how long this has been around, but it works on oldish Intel (MacBookPro11,3) as well as M3 Pro (Mac15,6).